# Where to write debugView commands

Tags: android, firebase, adb, firebase-analytics

I'm using firebase analytics for my app and want to check immediately if events were logged so i found debugView, and google says that i should write this:

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app PACKAGE_NAME
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.
```

the question is where should i write these commands. I tried write it in terminal in android studio but it says that adb isn't recognized(i' m windows user, maybe this is the problem but is there any solution for windows?).

Comment: The issue isn't where you type the command.  The issue is knowing where the adb program is and making sure it's in your shell path or typing its path fully.